# Find the marginal PDF and name its distribution

Tags: probability

My question:

If $X_{1}, X_{2}$ have the joint pdf

$$f(x_{1}, x_{2}) = \begin{cases} 6x_{1}x_{2}^{2} &: 0 <x_{1} < 1, 0 < x_{2} < 1\\ 0 &: \text{else} \end{cases}$$

and $Y_{1} = X_{1}X_{2}, Y_{2} = X_{1}\sqrt{X_{2}}$. what is the marginal pdf of $Y_{1}$, what kind of distribution does it have, and what are the parameters?

My work so far:

First I found the joint pdf of $Y_{1}, Y_{2}$ using

$$f_{{y_{1}}{y_{2}}}\left(y_{1}, y_{2}\right)=f_{x_{1}x_{2}}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)\cdot |J|$$

where J is the Jacobian, and having found $x_{1}=\frac{y_{2}^{2}}{y_{1}}$, $x_{2}=\frac{y_{1}^{2}}{y_{2}^{2}}$ and $|J|=\frac{2}{y_{2}}$,  we have

$$=6\left(\frac{y_{2}^{2}}{y_{1}}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{y_{1}^{2}}{y_{2}^{2}}\right)^{2} \cdot \frac{2}{y_{2}} $$

$$ = \frac{12y_{1}^{3}}{y_{2}^{3}}$$

So,

$$f_{{y_{1}}{y_{2}}}= \begin{cases} \frac{12y_{1}^{3}}{y_{2}^{3}} &: 0 < \frac{y_{2}^{2}}{y_{1}} < 1, 0 < \frac{y_{1}^{2}}{y_{2}^{2}} < 1\\ 0 &: \text{else} \end{cases}$$

Now here is where I am having some problems. I found the marginal pdf of $Y_{1}$ as

$$f_{y_{1}}\left(y_{1}\right)= \int^{\sqrt{y_{1}}}_{y_{1}}\frac{12y_{1}^{3}}{y_{2}^{3}} dy_{2}$$

$$=6y_{1}-6y_{1}^{2}$$.

This is not any specific distribution that I can identify. Any hints would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your last line should have $y_1$ instead of $y_2$

Comment: Does that look better?

Comment: It looks beta. @ChairmanMeow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your efforts are correct.  You should also note that the support is on $(0..1)$, that $6y(1-y)$ is a parabola and symmetric about $y=1/2$.

Less obvious is that $6=4!/2!^2$.

$$\begin{align}f_{\small Y_1}(y) &= 6y\,(1-y)\,\mathbf 1_{\small 0\lt y\lt 1}\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{(2+2)!}{2!~2!}\,y^{2-1}(1-y)^{2-1}\,\mathbf 1_{\small 0\lt y\lt 1} \end{align}$$

> This is not any specific distribution that I can identify. Any *hints* would be very helpful. Thanks.

You beta look for a family of supports defined over $(0..1)$ that are symmetrical (for some parameters, at least).

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for the help.